# Variation, combination, probability

Tags: combinatorics

I'm trying to calculate combination or different amount of variation we can have. E.g subway have 37 million different variations of sandwiches. I'm trying to calculate similar maths for my burger joint and want to know how many combination or variation of burger I have..
3 different meat
9 different cheese
13 different filling
6 different salad
12 different sauce

I would be grateful if anybody can help
Thanks

Comment: You need to be much clearer as to what types of combinations are allowed, what constitutes one combination from being "the same" as another and what constitutes one combination from being "different" than another.  Are you allowed multiple meats at a time or just one?  Are you allowed multiple cheese at a time?  Just one?  All? At most three?  How about fillings?

Comment: In similar problems several assumptions are commonly made.  For example, when calculating the number of drink options available you might allow "lemonade" as a drink base while also having "lemon flavor" as a drink additive.  Lemonade with raspberry is a valid drink, and so is Coke with lemon, but Lemonade with lemon is not since that is no different than just having regular lemonade without the additional lemon.

Comment: @Alien In case of duplicates, we generally flag the later one as the dupe of earlier one.  In this case, the two questions have *different* settings: the other question allows selecting three meat, whereas in the answer for this question, only one meat is allowed.  A Subway customer will find this an appropriate assumption.

Answer (score 1):

I will assume the following things:

- Every sandwich uses exactly one type of meat
- Every sandwich uses at most two types of cheese
- Every sandwich uses any number of toppings (fillings)
- Every sandwich uses exactly one type of salad
- Every sandwich uses at most two types of sauce
- Two sandwiches are considered the same so long as the list of ingredients is the same (*even if the order of the ingredients or the quantity of ingredients may differ, e.g. "extra cheese" or "chicken - cheese" vs "cheese - chicken"*)

In doing so, I hope that it should be clear how to modify the approach to satisfy whatever specific requirements your problem has.

We repeatedly apply the [rule of product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_product) and [rule of sum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_sum) and break apart via steps:

- Pick which meat is used:  $3$ options
- Pick which zero, one, or two cheese is used

  - If zero cheese: $1$ option (*the no-cheese*)
  - If one cheese: $9$ options
  - If two cheese: $\binom{9}{2}=36$ options.  Adding these gives a total of $1+9+\binom{9}{2}=46$ options
- Pick which if any toppings are used:  $2^{13}$ options
- Pick which salad is used: $6$ options
- Pick which sauce is used: $1+12+\binom{12}{2} = 79$ options

Multiplying the number of options for each step we get a total of:

$$3\times 46\times 2^{13}\times 6\times 79 = 535855104$$

Notes: when picking the toppings to be used, since we allowed any, all, or any other number of toppings to be used, we effectively count the [power set](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Power_set) of the set of toppings.  Equivalently worded, we sequence a series of yes/no questions and ask "do we use this topping? yes/no?" a dozen times in a row, once for each topping.

As an aside, 37 million sounds far too low for the number of sandwich offerings at Subway.

Comment: You are able to have 1-2-3 of the meats an one or all of the other options

Comment: @MZafar And?  The answer I gave should have plenty of information to allow you to finish the problem to match your intended interpretation.  I encourage you to try.