# confused please help

Tags: combinatorics

What would be my variation

E.g subway have 37 million different variations of sandwiches. I'm trying to calculate similar maths for my burger joint and want to know how many combination or variation of burger I have

3 different meat 
9 different cheese 
13 different filling 
6 different salad
 12 different sauce

Your able to pick 1., 2 or all 3 meat 
Also 1,2,3 or all cheeses together and so on..

I would be grateful if anybody can help Thanks

Comment: Repeating the [same](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3109638/variation-combination-probability) [question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3109417/variation-combination-probability) several times is not the way. Even as a newbie, you're allowed to edit your own posts to improve them.

Comment: @jmerry At the beginning it's said a *variant*.  Even as an experienced user, one *cannot* [edit his/her own question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/25490/290189) in a way that render previous answer incorrect because "a question is *not* a moving target".  It's OK to start a new question.

Comment: One of those questions I linked was essentially identical to this one, posted earlier, with no answer. There was no good excuse for posting this one rather than editing that one.

Answer (score 5):

You should also be able to choose no cheese, no sauce, but perhaps not no meat.

Each item may or may not be included (this give two options for each item.)

But we definitely shouldn't count the nothing-burger (no meat, no cheese, no sauce, etc.)

$(2^3)(2^9)(2^{13})(2^6)(2^{12}) - 1$

or

$(2^3 - 1)(2^9)(2^{13})(2^6)(2^{12})$

Depending on your definitions, is a burger without meat really a burger?

Comment: Upvote for your “burger without meat” comment. 

Answer (score 1):

For meat picking, picking one, two, or three kinds of meat is $\binom{3}{1}+\binom{3}{2}+\binom{3}{3}=7$, for cheese picking, picking one, two, three, or all kinds of cheese is $\binom{9}{1}+\binom{9}{2}+\binom{9}{3}+\binom{9}{9}=130$, and the same applies for filling = 378, salad = 42, and sause = 299. Thus, your final answer would be 7*130*378*42*299 = 4319700840, or about 4.3 billion for your burger joint.

Comment: But you can have a burger with just 1-2-3 meat rest is all option you can have either one of each or all of the option or none